# Javascript won't work in php code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this code, and it of course cannot show inside the php echo, because of the "" and ''. But I still want that effect, when you press the input the input value goes away, and that kind of thing. How can I do so? This is my code, that is bugging me:

```html
<input name="navn" size="33" style="background-color: rgba(39, 36, 28, 0.8); border:none; height:45px; width:450px; color:#b5aa83; padding:15px; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;" value="Navn" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Navn';}"
 onfocus="if (this.value == 'Navn') {this.value = '';}">
```

Comment: have you tried to wrap it in a function?

Comment: Actually I haven't. How can I call the function, inside an input field?

Comment: This is working example using js. Define the problem with your php code.

Comment: Escape either the single or double quotes

Comment: I am writing in dreamweaver and it gives me a syntax error, because the echo is inside "" which gives a problem with the above code.

Comment: Since the code above is using both single and double quotes, I cannot use just the one of them.

Comment: actually it works just fine http://codepen.io/Fowler/pen/vGxRLb Stop using dreamweaver - it's bad :) Also - looks like the 'placeholder' attribute is what you're trying to achieve. Why not use it instead?

Comment: Just FYI you could use the `placeholder` attribute instead of your `onblur`/`onfocus` evnts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Misunderstood the question, disregard.**

You should wrap your functions into an external JS file, your CSS also. It seems you're trying to create a placeholder, am I right? Maybe you should simply use HTML's "placeholder" attribute.

The input is not accessible unless you pass it to the function via "this" when using an external function. I'm not sure why your function does not recognize it when it's inline, but as external function with this passed as parameter, it works:

Javascript:

```
function onFocus(input){
  console.log(input.value);

  if(input.value === 'Navn'){
    input.value = '';
  } 

  console.log("On focus");
}
```

HTML:

```
<input name="navn" size="33" style="background-color: rgba(39, 36, 28, 0.8); border:none; height:45px; width:450px; color:#b5aa83; padding:15px; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;" value="Navn" onblur="onBlur(this);" onfocus="onFocus(this);">
```

http://jsbin.com/feqanopepi/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 2):

Simple Escape your quotes

```
echo "<input name=\"navn\" size=\"33\" style=\"background-color: rgba(39, 36, 28, 0.8); border:none; height:45px; width:450px; color:#b5aa83; padding:15px; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;\" value=\"Navn\" onblur=\"if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Navn';}\"
 onfocus=\"if (this.value == 'Navn') {this.value = '';}\">";
```